# Getting a strange _tkinter.TclError: unknown option

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have made a small game where you progress through your life much like instlife but made in python with Tkinter. It is not complete and no where near being completed as i always get this same error.

This is my code

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("275x400")
window.title("Life")

year = 1980
age = 0

def ageButton():
      global year
      global age
      year += 1
      age += 1
      yearText.configure(text=year)
      dynamicText.configure("You are %d" %age)


yearText = tkinter.Label(window, text=year, anchor="n", width="270")
dynamicText = tkinter.Label(window, text="You are %d" %age, anchor="n", 
width="270", height="495")
ageButton = tkinter.Button(window, text="Age", width="270",
command=ageButton)



ageButton.pack()
yearText.pack()
dynamicText.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

this is the error i get

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Lifee2\Life2.py", line 16, in ageButton
    dynamicText.configure("You are %d" %age)
  File "C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1472, in _configure
    return self._getconfigure1(_flatten((self._w, cmd, '-'+cnf)))
  File "C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1460, in _getconfigure1
    x = self.tk.splitlist(self.tk.call(*args))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-You are 1"
```

Comment: You have to specify an option for `.configure()` to configure - you did it right in the line above.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `configure` method, you must tell tkinter what value you are changing. In your case you need to change this:

```
dynamicText.configure("You are %d" %age)
```

... to this:

```
dynamicText.configure(text="You are %d" %age)
```